# Problems in setup QT for Android apps development: "SDK manager runs (requires exactly java 1.8)" and "Platform SDK Installed"

Tags: java, android, qt, android-ndk, development-environment

I'm trying to setup Qt creator for development of Android Apps. I followed the steps in the Qt documentation guide but these problem are occuring and I'm not finding a solution.

[image]

Qt version installed is: 1.14,
QtCreator version is: 4.11,
Java version is: jre1.8.0_261,
JDK version is: jdk-14.0.2,
NDK version is: 21.3.6528147

OS: Windows 10 home edition.

I setupped the environment variables for java and jdk.
What I need more to make it works well?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to try using JDK 8 instead.

Comment: I tried, but as you can see in the image, is the Android SDK that is having errors, not the JDK. Replacing the JDK the Android SDK errors remained.

Comment: The image shows JDK 14 being used, and the error could be a result of the Android SDK Manager requiring a specific version of the JDK.

Comment: You were right. I tried but for some unknown reason Qt was not updating to the JDK 8.
Now it works fine! Thank you Michael!

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was simply tools > options > device > andriod, then change the JDK loction to an empty folder, then a window will pop up asking you if you want to download everything

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same issue.

In my case (Ubuntu 22.04, QtCreator 9.0.1) QC expected sdkmanager executable at ~/android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager.

I've downloaded command line tools from https://developer.android.com/studio , copied into ~/android/sdk and moved binaries to latest/ subdirectory.

So sdkmanager was found by QC; everything started to work.